# What was that giant shadow with the glowing red eyes at the end of the Thriller Bark arc?

Tags: one-piece

At the end of the Thriller Bark Chapter 490 in manga and episode 381 in anime. I noticed strange giant shadows with glowing red eyes at the background. What could it be?

*Check this image in manga:*

[image]

*In Anime:*
[image]

Comment: It's florian triangle monster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it's an entity related to the [Florian Triangle](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Florian_Triangle).

> - According to Kokoro, many pirate and commercial ships mysteriously go missing every year and, sometimes, a ship will be found sailing without any people aboard. It has also been said that there are many haunted ships with dead bodies sailing across the sea (though, it is revealed that all this is attributed to Brook).
> - Though, some of the disappearances that have happened in the Triangle can be attributed to Moriah's scheme. Ships have been disappearing mysteriously in it for a long time before he came on his ship, Thriller Bark, ten years before the series. **This mystery is confirmed by an unknown ominous entity larger than Thriller Bark that was barely seen by Captain Lola through the fog. It is so large that it completely dwarfs Thriller Bark, the world's largest pirate ship, in sheer size, possibly making it the world's biggest creature to appear in the series thus far.**

---

It **may** also be possible that it's the trope "[Real After All](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealAfterAll)":

> If an episode revolves around a haunting (or alien visitation) (or lake monster sighting) (or whatever) that turns out to be a hoax, the episode will end with a shot of a real ghost/alien visitor/lake monster/whatever.

However, knowing Oda, that is highly unlikely. I just stated it as **it is possible** that we may never get to know what those entities were.

Comment: For all that, it looks uncomfortably similar to the shadows from sky islands. (you are right though)

Comment: @Kaine Which shadow from sky island? The only one I remember seeing is Klabautermann. It's seen around 3 years since I watched it, so I seem to have forgotten..

Comment: The shadows are not on sky island but shadows of people on sky islands visible in fog that appear gigantic due to the distance. They appear just before the sky island arc and there happens to be one in the most recent anime episode. There is a flashback of Bellamy seeing Luffy in one.  When first introduced though, these shadows were interpreted to be gigantic terrifing unidentified beings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the triangle is related to Enel. My theory goes like this:

Birka is exactly over the triangle and because of the deepflying Sky Island, there is always that mist. The shadows in the background are people of that Sky Island who survived Enel's genocide. Enel came to Skypiea 8 years ago (10 after time skip) — maybe he left Birka around the time when Moria arrived. Before that, Enel killed with his Devil Fruit all travelers either to train his power or by mistake (with attacks like Raigo's). That covers the 3 problems:

1. the mist
2. the shadows at the end, and
3. the missing people before Gecko's arrival.

Answer (score -1):

I think that these shadows are other elephants like Zunisha http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Zunisha

Comment: What makes you think that? I can similarly think something else than provide a link. Please substantiate your answer.